# History Question re Euler's Constant $\gamma$

Tags: math-history

What used to be be called "Euler's Constant" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulers_constant) is now frequently called the "Euler-Mascheroni Constant".

I have tried to find out what contribution Mascheroni made that merited his name being added to Euler's. All I have been able to turn up is that Mascheroni calculated $\gamma$ to a few more decimal places than Euler but the calculation had errors.

I assume Mascheroni did more than this for many authors to use "Euler-Mascheroni" for the name of $\gamma$ ? Any information on what his contribution was would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the third paragraph of http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Mascheroni.html answer your question?

Comment: I looked at that reference before posting my question. In my opinion it does not answer my question.

Comment: I guess you'll have to read the source and make your mind about Mascheroni's contribution and the claim that "Mascheroni's work shows a deep understanding of Euler's calculus". See  https://archive.org/details/adnotationesadc00mascgoog

Comment: Lagarias says: At that time constants were often named after a
person who had done the labor of computing them to the most digits.....In the current era, which credits the mathematical
contributions, it seems most appropriate to name the constant after Euler alone.

Comment: lhf - thanks for the reference but I think I will have to rely on secondary sources in languages I understand.

Comment: Will Jagy - thanks for the quote from Lagarias however the time order seems to be the reverse. The constant was named after Euler alone in the past and Mascheroni's name has been added in modern times.

Comment: Well, his pdf is at the wikipedia article, see pages 555-556.

Comment: I use "Euler-Mascheroni constant" because "Euler's constant" is slightly ambiguous to me - IIRC some people use this to mean $e$.

Comment: I believe $\pi$ is known as "the Ludolphian number" in certain countries.  Because Ludolph Van Ceulen computed it to many places.

Answer (score 1):

Your investigation into Lorenzo Mascheroni’s role in the history of Euler’s constant $\gamma$ led to the correct conclusion.  An authoritative historic and survey article on Euler’s constant is given in Jeffrey Lagarias’ paper “*[Euler’s Constant: Euler’s Work and Modern Developments](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2013-50-04/S0273-0979-2013-01423-X/S0273-0979-2013-01423-X.pdf)*” October 2013 Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, 50(4), 527–628.  If you haven’t already read Lagarias’ article, Mascheroni’s contribution is discussed in Section 2.6 on pages 555-556, and the article states that he merely contributed four more correct digits to Euler’s computed 15-digit approximation (but Mascheroni’s published expression contained 32 digits).

Lagarias mentions that at that point in history, it was not uncommon to name constants after the person who had gone through the “*... labor of computing them to the most digits*.” Lagarias’ historical exposition is quite detailed, and it seems unlikely that he would have omitted any more significant contribution that Mascheroni might have made regarding $\gamma.$  Given this, he says that it's probably most appropriate that $\gamma$ be named for Euler alone.

But if it turns out that the Grothendieck constant $k_R$ is the reciprocal of $\gamma$, I think that might warrant a hyphenated appellation. :)